# How Can I Encourage Google to scan New robots.txt File?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I just updated my robots.txt file on a new site; Google Webmaster Tools reports it read my robots.txt 2 days before my last update.
my last robots.txt had a "disallow: all" raw.

Is there any way I can encourage Google to re-read my robots.txt as soon as possible?

for now, google isn't scanning my site. Please help me!

Comment: Have you contacted the goole folken?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to force Google to crawl and index your site by using the "Fetch as Google" functionality explained here:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1352276?hl=en

After that, Google should honor the new robots.txt.